# CONTENT_DISPOSITION is ignored and pdf downlods with name download.pdf

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am facing a problem in naming a pdf which an api provides. But the default name in save window is always download.pdf even after setting CONTENT_DISPOSITION. 
Tried with
1.  mediaType = application/pdf and MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE. 
2. Given space after attachment;

```
@RequestMapping(value = "manifestpdf/{logId}" ,method = RequestMethod.GET/*,produces =MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE*/)
public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getManifestPdf(@RequestHeader(value = HEADER_TENANT_ID) String Id,@PathVariable("logId") String logsId){
    S3ObjectInputStream response = Services.getManifestPdf(Id,logId);
    return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.valueOf("application/pdf"))
        //.header("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=testing.pdf")
          .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=manifest.pdf")
        .header(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL,"no-cache")
        .body(new InputStreamResource(response));
```

The name of download I try to make is manifest.pdf. Somebody please help.

Thanks & regards,

Comment: Based on the [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) the filename should be enclosed in doublequotes. Does that help?

Comment: yes. Tried this too. .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "manifest.pdf")

Comment: Try `.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"manifest.pdf\"")` instead.

Comment: Tried. Still no difference.But when I  see the response headers , 
Content-Disposition →attachment; filename="manifest.pdf" is displayed

Comment: What browser do you use? Also, is it the same in another one also? If the headers are going through, then... hmmm...

Comment: Tried in Postman and RestClient.

Comment: Haha, [Postman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2082) has a bug with this, was fixed literally 2 days ago. In RestClient I could not make Content-Disposition header work at all. Can you try in a regular Chrome/FF/IE browser?